# MongoDB expire event on node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, events, mongoose

I want to catch mongodb collection expire event on node.js using mongoose model.
For example if I have this collection

```
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        expires: 60*60,
    }
})
```

When document created it will be deleted after 1 hour. I want to call node js function when this document is deleted. For example I have this function

```
function log(name) {
    console.log('document with name ' + name + ' was successfully removed');
}
```

And I want to call this function for each document when they are being removed.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible with MongoDB. MongoDB does not have any notification feature built-in. You could however implement the same method Meteor uses by tailing the `oplog`, but even then that's a really tricky situation. I'll write an answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment, MongoDB doesn't have any notify features built-in. You could implement the same method Meteor uses by tailing MongoDBs `oplog`, but that's going to take *a lot* of work.

The only fairly simple and reasonable solution is to do this on the application-level and not database-level by using something like [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) (`npm install node-schedule --save`).

Here's an example:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', mySchema);

Model.create({ name: 'Michael' }, function(err, doc) {
  if (err) return console.error(err); // Handle the error
  var now = new Date();
  var when = new Date(now).setHours(now.getHours() + 1);
  schedule.scheduleJob(when, function() {
    // This callback will fire in one hour
  });
});
```

The issue with this is that the callback will fire even if MongoDB has crashed or similar and couldn't remove the document. Another issue is that if your app crashes, your schedule callback is lost.